# How to efficiently resize image with antialias?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics, android-paint

I try to resize an image like this:

```
aPaint.setAntiAlias(true); // Enabling this flag will cause all draw operations that support antialiasing to use it.
aPaint.setFilterBitmap(True); // enable bilinear sampling on scaled bitmaps. If cleared, scaled bitmaps will be drawn with nearest neighbor sampling, likely resulting in artifacts.
apaint.setDither(true); // Enabling this flag applies a dither to any blit operation where the target's colour space is more constrained than the source.
aCanvas.drawBitmap(aBitmap, aJSrcRect, aJDestRectf, apaint);
```

But I don't have a very good antialised image (it's antialiased, but not very good). Here is an image showing my problem

[image]

What can i do to increase the quality of the antialias under android ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For antialias effect, you can try to create a Paint like this:

```
Paint paint= new Paint();
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Finally apply paint on canvas with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0.f, 0.f, paint)
```

Comment: paint.setAntiAlias(true); is just a helper for paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); :( as you see in the sample code i gave it's already what i did :(